# Calculate definite integral $\int_0^{\pi/2} 3\sin x\cos x/(x^2-3x+2)\; dx$

Tags: calculus

Please help to calculate definite integral

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{3\sin x\cos(x)}{x^2-3x+2} \, dx.
$$

I feel that there is a trick somewhere, but I cannot understand where?

Comment: Hint: $\sin(x)\,\cos(x)= \frac{1}{2}\,\sin(2\,x)$

Comment: You can't the denominator has singularities at $x=1$ and $2$. Even the existence of an anti-derivative for this function is questionable. However, I believe that this is a prime candidate for Residue Calculus, if you like Cauchy Principal values.

Comment: This integral has a pole at $x=1$ and therefore diverges.  Principal value?

Comment: @Zach466920: This is far from a "prime candidate" for residue calculus, poles or no.  The conbination of the trig functions and the polynomial in the denominator and the finite limits would make this a holy mess.

Comment: I would file this integral as near impossible, at least with the Limits given, now that I realize the poles...

Comment: @RonGordon I got the residues, but I forgot about the infinite limit requirement.

Comment: @RonGordon : The fact that it has a pole (in fact it has two) falls short of justifying the statement "therefore it diverges".  However, the particular nature of each of the poles implies the integral of the absolute value of this function is infinite.  Perhaps it has a principal value.

Comment: @Zach466920 : Maybe it lacks an antiderivative in closed form, but certainly on each of the intervals bounded by the poles an antiderivative exists.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I was referring to this particular case.

Comment: @RonGordon : The thing about this particular case that implies that the function is not Lebesgue integrable is not simply that it has poles; rather it is something about the particular nature of the poles, which you didn't mention, so the word "therefore" exceeds what you are justified in saying.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Uncle.  This is where my knowledge base becomes weak.  I will have to review my long-yellowed notes.

Comment: Maybe you could write this as a Taylor series? I don't know if the series has a nice form though.

Answer (score 2):

Setting $t=2x$ and dropping the $3$, the integral becomes

$$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin(t)}{(t-2)(t-4)}\,dx=\frac12\int_0^{\pi}\sin(t)\left(\frac1{t-4}-\frac1{t-2}\right)dx.$$

An integral like
$$\int\frac{\sin(t)}{t-a}dt$$
can be handled by translating

$$\int\frac{\sin(t)\cos(a)+\cos(t)\sin(a)}tdt,$$
which results in a combination of sine and cosine integrals

$$\cos(a)\text{Si}(t)+\sin(a)\text{Ci}(t).$$

The singularity can be moved by using the related $\text{Cin}$ function

$$\int\frac{\cos(t)}{t}dt=\int\left(\frac1t-\frac{1-\cos(t)}t\right)dt=\ln(t)-\text{Cin}(t)+C.$$

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a simple closed formula for the definite integral.

Answer (score 0):

By using:
$$ \int\frac{\sin(2x)}{x-a}\,dx = \sin(2a)\,\text{Ci}(2x-2a)-\cos(2a)\,\text{Si}(2a-2x)\tag{1}$$
where $\text{Si}$ and $\text{Ci}$ are the [sine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) and [cosine integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html), we have:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\text{PV}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{3\sin x\cos x}{(x-1)(x-2)}\,dx = \frac{3}{2}&\cdot&\left[\left(\text{Ci}(2)-\text{Ci}(2-\pi)\right)\sin 2+\left(\text{Ci}(4-\pi)-\text{Ci}(4)\right)\sin 4\right.\\&+&\left.\left(\text{Si}(2-\pi)-\text{Si}(2)\right)\cos 2+\left(\text{Si}(4)-\text{Si}(4-\pi)\right)\cos 4\right]\end{eqnarray*}$$
so:
$$ \text{PV}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{3\sin x\cos x}{(x-1)(x-2)}\,dx = 0.33997326\ldots-\frac{3\pi i \sin 2}{2}\tag{2}$$
where the imaginary part only comes from the term $\text{Ci}(2-\pi)$.

$(1)$ is straightforward to prove through differentiation.